# Backbone coffeescript behaviour - data ignores all IF statements and passes anyway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a mystic behavior in my website.. I have data which ignores all IF statements in its way and passes all requirements it has'nt. I'm sure i dont have similar functions, tis the only one. But Data transfers are like 50/second(PUT to DB), it's my first so big website and this problem i cant solve. I even tryed if the found_item is not defined after this call, it creates empty object anyway.

```
// my View

  ....# 600 lines of code
  found_item = []
  get_items_from_killed_monster: ->
    item = []
    item[1] = itemname: "medicine1"
    ....
    item[110] = itemname: "weapon"
    drop_random_number = randomInt(1,10)
    if drop_random_number > 5
      found_item = item[1]
    else
      found_item = item[110]
    if found_item.itemname is "medicine1"
      @model.set(medicine1: @model.attributes.medicine1+1)
      @model.save()    ## its working, im getting that medicine
    if found_item.itemname is "weapon"
      router.send_item_to_inventory(found_item)  ##sending it to Router



// My Router
  send_item_to_inventory: (attributes) ->
    if attributes.itemname is "weapon"
      @view = new Sprint.Views.Inventories.IndexView(inventories: @inventories)
      @view.create_item(attributes)
      console.log(attributes)
      ## console says: Object {itemname: "medicine1"}
      ## it passed somehow !

// My Inventories.indexview
  create_item: (attributes) ->
    if attributes.itemname is "weapon"
      this.collection = new Sprint.Collections.InventoriesCollection
      this.model = new this.collection.model(item: attributes.name)
      this.collection.create(this.model.toJSON())
      console.log(attributes)
      ## console says: Object {itemname: "medicine1"}
      ## it passed somehow ! The object is created with itemname: "medicine1"
```

Comment: `console.log` puts a live reference into the console so it won't necessarily have the same contents when it is used and when you look at it. You can `console.log JSON.stringify(attributes)` or `console.log _(attributes).clone()` to get around that. Also, stop creating models, `toJSON`ing them, and handing that to `collection.create`, just set up the collection properly and hand the attributes to `collection.create`; you're doing more work than necessary and creating duplicate models that no longer have any connection with each other.

Comment: As far as helping you goes, you need to provide a minimal functional demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com for this sort of thing, make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: Yes, sorry i didnt know how i could explain that. I found the solution. I played alot with javascript console and found, that inside my code is invisible "old" code, which procedures. I copied my code into notepad, deleted the file, created new file with same name and put there code. And it worked. So, its mystic, how does this invisible code appear.. And thx, i will fix my code like you say.